# Removing only first column in R using uploaded data

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

All, I'm very new to R and have no programming experience.  I'm using a loop to load hundreds of Excel sheets, perform a statistical test, and spit out the results.  So effectively hundreds of those regressions.  I'm using a "dummy header" in the first column of my Excel sheets so that I can save the R outputs by the names of the different Excel sheets.  I want to drop that dummy header from my regression, as it's interfering with some of the regressions.  I've tried using.

`x<-mydata[,1]
newdata<-subset(mydata,select=-x))`

But that doesn't work, it return's either

invalid argument to unary operator
Error in x[j] : invalid subscript type 'list'
or
Error: Unsupported index type: data.frame

depending on how I change the code.  Any help or insight would be much appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: `mydata=mydata[ ,-1]` will remove the first column. However, based on your description there are likely several other ways to improve your code and workflow. If you show us all the relevant code you're running, we can probably help you implement a more streamlined process.

Comment: You have a header in a column? Doesn't seem likely.  Do you mean in a **row**? A reproducible example would be delightful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are reading in csv files, you can use the skip argument within the read.csv function. If you have headers for the column names below the dummy header, you will want to set it to true.  If you don't have column headers then use the skip function and set headers to false.

```
#with headers
data<-read.csv("file.csv", skip=1, header=TRUE)

#without headers
data<-read.csv("file.csv", skip=1, header=FALSE)
```

If you are using the read.xlsx function you should be able to use the the rowIndex argument.  You may have to set the length to a large number so all rows read in properly. Starting at row 2 will get rid of the top row.

```
sample<-read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, rowIndex = 2:1000000)
```